# The Class Of All Possible Worlds

Tags: logic, set-theory, modal-logic

Is the class of all possible worlds a proper class? I guess that you could say that under a function any possible world can be defined as a set, and hence the class of all possible worlds would be bijective to the universe of all sets which is a proper class.
Like the following.

Assume, that for all possible worlds $W$ there exists a bijective function $F$ such that it turns a possible world $W$ to a corresponding set $X$.
$$\forall W[\;\exists F: W\to X\;]$$
Now assume there exists a class of all possible worlds $W$ called $\mathscr{L}$, well if that is true then one could also say the exists a class of all sets $V$ (Universe of all sets). Well given the statement above would it also be reasonable to say that there exists a bijective function $G: \mathscr{L}\to  V$, and hence couldn't the class of all possible worlds $\mathscr{L}$ be classified as a proper class because $V$ is also a proper class?

But is this proof correct?

Comment: I am sorry for the stupid question. What is the definition of a world (some "smaller" version of a universe maybe?)?

Comment: By possible worlds, I mean a possible world of modal logic, usually under the following definition. "A possible world is a complete and consistent way the world is or could have been. Possible worlds are widely used as a formal device in logic, philosophy, and linguistics in order to provide semantics for intensional and modal logic"

Comment: That seems a bit sketchy :) the important part is how much structure you put that restricts your possible worlds. For example the collection of all finite sets already forms a class (well, even the collection of singeltons is a proper class). So you really want to get a rigorous definition.

Comment: I agree however I haven't been taught a definition of possible worlds which can be expressed in first-order logic.

Comment: That's a shame. Sounds like a real fun question. Unfortunately, I don't know much about logic. Looking forward to the insights of the experts.

Comment: Well, still thanks for trying.

Comment: Let's assume we are working with a classical logic so there is no neither true nor false propositions. Now there will be a function $f:\mathbb{P}\rightarrow 2^{W}$ since any single propositions is either true or false in some world $w$. Now assuming there are a proper class amount of propositions(which can be easily argued by looking at all the propositions true about the universe of sets for example), then we can see that the class  W is a proper class too, as it contains the actual world and it has to contain every single true state of affairs about the universe of sets $\mathbb{V}$.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as "possible worlds," therefore there is no "class of all possible worlds." That's a semantical addition. In theory, what we have is either referential Propositional Logic (+ Transitivity Predicate), or its first-order counterpart.

What you are referring to as "Possible world" is a Kripkean coinage (The so-called Kripke semantics) to make sense of ridiculously nested-valuations. What you can *really* ask is: is "the class of all nested valuation" a proper class... I haven't got a clue what that would even mean.

By the way, I am not saying semantics is useless, etc. What I am saying is: your question is equivalent to asking, "what's the weight of justice." Just like Justice has no weight because it's an abstract concept. There is no class of "Possible worlds" because it's an abstract concept we use to make sense of the apparently unintuitive syntax of modal logic.

For example, when talking about Modal Propositional logic the So-called set of possible worlds $W$ in the tuple $\langle W, R, \bar a, v \rangle$ is just some finite subset of $\mathbb N$. From this we get reference dependent valuation in the ordered pair $(v(P),i)$; where $i\in W \subseteq \mathbb N$. Now, if you mean a proper subclass in this sense of "Possible world" i.e. $W\subseteq\mathbb N$ that I just explained, then that becomes trivial since we can forget about possible worlds, and just consider some arbitrary subset of $\mathbb N$

One trivial fact comes to mind, the class [or in terms of ZFC, set] of set "All possible worlds" and $\scr P(\mathbb N)$ are equidimensional. One more, perhaps, even more trivial fact is that the two are identical. That is, the "class of all possible world" if it were to exist would just be $\scr P(\mathbb N)$

As for the last part, is there a bijection between the class of all possible worlds and the class of all sets? That's resounding no, since $|\scr P(\mathbb N)|\lt|\scr P(\mathbb R)|$